# Error on Cloning a Git Repository to client machine

Tags: git, git-clone, git-remote

Hi everyone I have pushed my Git bare repository to our cloud server with 
    scp -r project.git root@serverip:/home/gitrepos

That worked fine. Now I am trying to clone it to another location with
    git clone root@serverip:/home/gitrepos/project.git

I enter the password when requested. Then I get this error.

```
stdin: is not a tty
bash: git-upload-pack: command not found
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I have another server which I purchased from Godaddy and it works fine when I clone from that.

Why does this happen on this server? Do I need to install anything on the server? I know similar things have been discussed in other posts but I just cant understand. Can someone explain it simply so I can understand? Thanks

Comment: It looks like `git`  is not installed on the server.

Comment: yes I installed git and it is working now. Still says stdin: is not a tty, but it clones. Thanks for that. I am new to Git.

Comment: please try `git clone ssh://root@serverip:/home/gitrepos/project.git`, you need specify the protocol to transfer data.